# Vlookup/transpose with range

Tags: excel, vlookup, transpose

I am trying to vlookup transpose with ranges.
These are stock coverage report of mobile spare parts. whatever we have covered the stock buffer to updated status against corresponding to the ranges an ascending order. (how many mobile stock covered-like 1,2,10,20)

Anyone help it would be appreciated.

```html
DATA  
DESCRIPTION MODLE STATUS
Apricot 11 DONE
Avocado 10 DONE
Banana 8 DONE
Bilberry 7 DONE
Blackberry 16 DONE
Blackcurrant 20 DONE
Blueberry 2 DONE

DESIRED RESULT                    
AREA 7320 5520 5510 3320 1102 1100 950 940 930 920 919 918 917 916 915 914 913 912 911 910
Blueberry                   DONE DONE
Blackcurrant DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE
Blackberry     DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE
Bilberry              DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE
Banana             DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE
Avocado           DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE
Apricot          DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE DONE
```

[image: spreadsheet example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following formula in B13, assuming the top is at A1, and then fill to the right and bottom:

`=IF(COUNT($B$12:$U$12)<VLOOKUP($A13,$A$3:$C$9,2,FALSE)+COLUMN(A13),"DONE","")`
I assume there's a better way to find the length of the range than just hardcoding it as `$B$12:$U$12`.

Comment: thank you so much. you are great. Formula working fine.I follow and try to apply your formula one sheet to another sheet but its return output different.Please help me how do rectify the issue. if possible explain the formula little bit. I am not familiar to excel. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. The formula works by checking that the item's MODLE column plus the column number is a higher value than the total number of columns for the different areas. You can get very good help on the formulas by just typing `=if` followed by F1, or `=vlookup` followed by F1 into any cell. Also search the internet for how cell references in Excel work.

Comment: thanks you so much for your explanation and reply.Its help to understand the formula.